# Cannot update entity using extension of DbSet

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository-pattern

I got problem when update database by using entity framework. The *m_entities* set has been changed when method *Update(T x)* called but *SaveChanges()* return 0. I had debug and the entity state still *unchanged*. This is my Repository class.

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly IApplicationDbContext m_context;
    internal IDbSet<T> m_entities;
    public Repository(IApplicationDbContext m_context)
    {
        this.m_context = m_context;
        this.m_entities = this.m_context.Set<T>();
    }
    public void Update(T x)
    {
        this.m_entities.AddOrUpdate(x);
    }
    public void SaveChanges()
    {
        this.m_context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

The DbContext class

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>, IApplicationDbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("name=DefaultConnection")
    {
        this.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
        this.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
    }
}
```

And connection string.

```
<connectionStrings>
<!--<add providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=LWCGRGTG75SJU9M; Initial Catalog=HPDB; MultipleActiveResultSets=true; Integrated Security=False; User Id=sa; Password=123456"/>-->
```

Comment: because `this.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled` is set to false;

Answer (score 1):

if you change

```
this.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
```

to

```
this.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;
```

Effectively, you are telling EF to not track changes and thus the state will always be unchanged.

If you want to leave it off, you can add it to the tracker manually like so

```
this.m_context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Added; //or EntityState.Modified
```